# What is the start icon on the partition on the gnome disk utility?

Tags: fedora, partition, fstab, disk

I tried googling it and just found this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234886 and this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1165437.

But it is not so clear.

So I thought the star icon represent a boot drive. And check my first drive the partition is 1.1GB ext4 bootable and the second partition is on LVM2 PV.
Then, but when I put my secondary internal drive, backup the data and convert it from ntfs to ext4, all the 3 partition on the second drive has the star icon.

The star icon will just show if the partition is mounted at startup. but  when I remove them in the /etc/fstab the star button is gone.

So what is really the star icon? If it is for the boot drive, my secondary drive is just for data, I will not boot from it. And so how I can remove the start icon without removing it from the /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping that reading manual will be enough, but the manual is very limited as well as the other documentation. So the source code had to come for help. Grepping through the code for "icon" keyword showed few occasions which sound like these icons:

```
src/disks/gduvolumegrid.c:    g_ptr_array_add (icons_to_render, (gpointer) "user-bookmarks-symbolic");
```

Checking the icon confirms they are the ones we are looking for:

The code shows, what is the trigger for this icon to get rendered:

```
if (element->show_configured)
  g_ptr_array_add (icons_to_render, (gpointer) "user-bookmarks-symbolic");
```

The `show_configured` is assigned when the device is "configured", whatever it means:

```
element->show_configured = is_block_configured (block);
```

We can probably simplify that to "gnome-disks known about this drive and about its configuration".